# How to set property in React state array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 React components Memory and children MemoryShape

At the Memory component i have method newGame which setting 4 random MemoryShapes to the purple color when i clicking on button, but when i clicked all shapes got purple color not 4 that i wants

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './memory.css';
import MemoryShape from './MemoryShape';
import randomShape from './helpers/help';

class Memory extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      memoryshapes: new Array(16).fill(Math.random() * 1321132),


    };

    this.preInitGame = this.preInitGame.bind(this);

    this.newGame = () => {
      const [...shapes] = this.state.memoryshapes;
      const coloredShapesIndexes = randomShape(4, 15);
      coloredShapesIndexes.forEach((value) => {
        shapes[value].shape.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
      });

      console.log(shapes);
      this.setState({ memoryshapes: shapes });
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.preInitGame();
  }


  preInitGame() {
    let [...memoryshapes] = this.state.memoryshapes;
    const data = {
      shape: {
        style: {
          setColor(nextColor) {
            this.backgroundColor = nextColor;
          },
          backgroundColor: 'green',
        },
      },
    };
    memoryshapes = memoryshapes.map((value) => {
      let newValue = value;
      newValue = data;

      return newValue;
    });

    this.setState({ memoryshapes });
  }


  render() {
    const shapes = this.state.memoryshapes.map((value, index) => {
      const arrkey = index + value;
      return (<MemoryShape
        key={arrkey}
        tabIndex={index}
        backgroundColor={value.shape.style.backgroundColor}
      />);
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {shapes}
        <br />
        <button
          style={{
            padding: 20,
            marginLeft: 300,
          }}
          onClick={this.newGame}
        >
          Start Game
        </button>
        <MemoryShape
          tabIndex={-124}
          backgroundColor="blue"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Memory;
```

```js
class MemoryShape extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { backgroundColor: 'green' };

    this.changeColor = () => {

    };
    this.handleKeyDown = () => {

    };
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps.backgroundColor);
    this.setState({ backgroundColor: nextProps.backgroundColor });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="memory-shape"
        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
        onClick={this.changeColor}
        role="button"
        tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex}
        backgroundColor={this.props.backgroundColor}
        style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor }}
      />
    );
  }
}

MemoryShape.propTypes = {
  backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
  tabIndex: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};
MemoryShape.defaultProps = {
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
};

export default MemoryShape;
```

Comment: Do you want to update your shapes object based on click?

Answer (score 2):

To set color for 4 random components first we need to get 4 random indexes of object on click. Based on your need I have done simple example to randomly set background color of component based on `onClick`. Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elumalaiit/65mt4zyc/3/). And working code is below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>React Color Change</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        class App extends React.Component {
          constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                shapes: [
                    {shape: "shape1", backgroundColor: "purple"}, 
                    {shape: "shape2", backgroundColor: "purple"}, 
                    {shape: "shape3", backgroundColor: "purple"},
                    {shape: "shape4", backgroundColor: "purple"}, 
                    {shape: "shape5", backgroundColor: "purple"}, 
                    {shape: "shape6", backgroundColor: "purple"},
                    {shape: "shape7", backgroundColor: "purple"}, 
                    {shape: "shape8", backgroundColor: "purple"}, 
                    {shape: "shape9", backgroundColor: "purple"},
                    {shape: "shape10", backgroundColor: "purple"}, 
                    {shape: "shape11", backgroundColor: "purple"}, 
                    {shape: "shape12", backgroundColor: "purple"},
                    {shape: "shape13", backgroundColor: "purple"}, 
                    {shape: "shape14", backgroundColor: "purple"}, 
                    {shape: "shape15", backgroundColor: "purple"},
                ]
            }
          }

          changeColor() {
            const shapes = this.state.shapes;

            shapes.map((data, i) => { // Reset already selected
                if(data.backgroundColor == "green")
                    data.backgroundColor = "purple";
            })

            // Generate 4 random indexes
            let rand_array = [];
            while(rand_array.length < 4){
                var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(shapes.length - 1)) + 1;
                if(rand_array.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
                rand_array[rand_array.length] = randomnumber;
            }

            //Update shape by generated indexes
            rand_array.map((data) => shapes[data].backgroundColor = "green");

            this.setState({shapes});
          }

          render(){
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.state.shapes.map((data, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Shapes data={data} changeColor={() => this.changeColor()}/>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            )
          }
        }

        const Shapes = (props) => {
            return (
                <div style={{backgroundColor: `${props.data.backgroundColor}`, padding: '5px', margin: "1%", width: "50%"}} 
                onClick={props.changeColor}>
                    {props.data.shape}
                </div>
            )
        }

        ReactDOM.render(
          <App/>, 
          document.getElementById("app")
        );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this will helps you!

Comment: yes, how to set color of 1 component with onclick i know! but i am trying to set 4 random components colors from 16 components and problem is all components gets new colors not 4 random components which i expected

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have unique property in array of objects! Just added id property and everything works!

Comment: Congrats for your own try!